# List Population In MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my `Model` Class:

```
 public class TechnicalCommitteeDetails
    {
 public List<String> Documents { get; set; }
        public List<String> Sites { get; set; }
        public List<String> Testing_Facility { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my `Controller` Class:

```
 public ActionResult TechnicalCommitteeDetails()
        {
 tcd.Documents.Add("Product Bullitiens");
            tcd.Documents.Add("MSD");
            tcd.Documents.Add("Technical Literature");
            tcd.Sites.Add("Pennsylvania");  
            tcd.Sites.Add("New York");
            tcd.Testing_Facility.Add("TEC Service");
            tcd.Testing_Facility.Add("Amercian Engineering Testing");

}
```

Here is my `View`:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Documents, new { @class = "col-xs-6 no-padding" })
```

**This give me output like this :**
[image]

I want that each Documnet appears to be in separate line like as follow:

```
 Documents: Product Bullitiens
            MSD
            Technical Literature
```

Comment: instead of this model => Model.Documents write as model => model .Documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could render the list manually instead of using the `@Html.DisplayFor()`.
Example:

```
<ul>
@foreach(var item in Model.Documents)
{
    <li>
        item
    </li>

}
</ul>
```

And just style the list the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your property `Documents` is a `List<string>` which by default will be rendered as you are seeing in your project.

One option would be to create a custom **DisplayTemplate** for displaying a list of string.

For this, you will need to create a new Folder called **DisplayTemplates** within your **Shared** folder under the **Views** folder. Views > Shared > DisplayTemplates Then within this create a new PartialView called **_Items.cshtml**

[image]

Within this new PartialView, put in the code;

```
@model List<String>

<ul>
    @foreach (var s in Model)
    {
        <li>@s</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Then update your `@Html.DisplayFor` code to be;

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Documents, "_items")
```

This will then render your Documents as an Unordered List. From here, you can play around with the layout and how you want the HTML markup to be in order to display the Documents.

By using this method, you have created a re-usable `DisplayFor` template for displaying lists of strings. You can then use this method to display other types of properties, e.g. a `List<TechnicalCommitteeDetails>` which could display a list of Committee details within displays a list of Documents.